# How do I create a DATE that starts and ends at 0600 every day

Tags: mysql, database, date, shift

My database collects data and stores in a database with date stamp (in fact two columns one date and another time. now my requirement is to have another column called date (just two digits of date ranging from 01 to 31) but the date should be changing at 06:00 hours instead of 00:00. so for example if date is 14th of Dec and time is 05:30, the DATE should return as 13 and should change to 14 only after 06:00 on 14th Dec. similarly if the date is 15th Dec and time is 03:00 , it should show 14 and not 15

please help in building a sql syntax to achieve the same.

Thanks in advance
Manjunath S

Comment: Date manipulation functions are not standardized, so we need to know which database dialect (and version) you need (Oracle, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, MySQL, SQLite, ...). Please tag the database in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I use mysql database. pardon me i do not understand what is tagging the data base.

Comment: You tagged [tag:date] and [tag:shift] *(not that I understand how you think the question is "related to the usage of the right and/or left shift key on the keyboard")*, so you should be able to understand tagging [tag:mysql].